# Weird javascript variable behavior

Tags: javascript

I was working on a project while I came across a strange problem. here is my code

```
let newEvent = event;
console.log(changes, event, newEvent);
newEvent.title = changes.title;
newEvent.description = changes.description;
console.log(changes, event, newEvent);
```

The first `console.log` outputted:

> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}
>
> {title: 'Event 1', description: ''}
>
> {title: 'Event 1', description: ''}

and this is what I expected, but what is didn't expect was the next `console.log` which outputted:

> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}
>
> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}
>
> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}

I expected the following output:

> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}
>
> {title: 'Event 1', description: ''}
>
> {title: 'Event 2', description: 'blaat'}

Is there anybody that can help me whit this problem, thanks id advance

Comment: `newEvent` is just a reference to `event` Read [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: `let newEvent = new Event()` would do the trick. You are using `newEvent` as a reference to `event`.